# Getting a valid CBUUID from a Bluetooth device for scanning

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am writing a simple device browser for a specific kind of Bluetooth device (a card reader). I understand you're supposed to pass in an array of services specified by CBUUIDs to the `scanForPeripherals(withServices:options:)` method.

To find these IDs, I've scanned without a service filter, found my device, and looked in `advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs"]` where I found a single 64-bit CBUUID looking something like this: `0x00000001c413e940`.

How do I convert this string into a valid CBUUID that I can pass in as a service filter? I have tried the `CBUUID(string:)` initialiser, but it just throws a runtime exception saying it's not a valid UUID.

I've also looked in the device's reference manual and found the following table:

[image]

However, none of these appear to work - no devices appear in the scan when filtering by these service UUIDs.

Finally, when I examine the device in [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/lightblue-explorer/id557428110?mt=8) it reports 1 service broadcasting (`FFF0`), but when I attempt to filter by this service, no devices show.

I'm starting to think the service filter is just plain broken. Does anyone ever actually use it?

**Update:** It works! I rebuilt and reinstalled the app and the device appeared when scanning with a service filter for `FFF0`. Thanks Paulw11 for your help.

Comment: A valid UUID looks like `36353433-3231-3039-3837-363534333231` or for "well-known" IDs, four hex digits such as `2A29`.  I suggest you use an app light LightBlue explorer to identify the UUID from your peripheral.

Comment: The reference manual for the bluetooth device has a list of UUIDs like `2A29` that it supposedly advertises, but when I tried filtering by that, nothing came up.

Comment: Well, that was just an example `2A29` is actually a UUID for the manufacturer name characteristic, not a service.  The list of well-known services is here - https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services.  Again, use LightBlue Explorer for the iOS app store to see what your peripheral is advertising.

Comment: LightBlue is a great app. Please see my edits.

Comment: Service filter works.  A peripheral has two "sets" of services; those that it offers and those that it advertises (which may be a subset of those that are offered).  The values listed in the table are characteristics, not services; e.g, the [*battery service*](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.battery_service.xml) (0x180f) has characteristic [*battery level*](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level.xml) with id 0x2A19.

Comment: The primary service for the device seems to be the "Smart card" service, which you have discovered with Light Blue seems to be using ID FFF0.  This isn't a legitimate assigned number, but it should still work.  A device typically won't advertise secondary services such as manufacturer information and battery level, but these can be discovered once you have connected to the device.